# UITableViewCell placeholder image

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm working with AFNetworking to load my images for cell placeholder. Here is my code example. (Token from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial))

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:daysWeather.weatherIconURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                      placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                   NSLog(@"Load placeholder img");
                                   weakCell.imageView.image = image;
                                   [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                               } failure:nil];

return cell;
```

And now I have a question. Does this images load every time, when it becomes visible? As you can see I've added `NSLog(@"Load placeholder img");` in success block. And I see, that this code calls every time, when cell becomes visible (after it was visible, disappeared and become visible again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes **success** block called every time. But AFNetworking will download the image only once and saved it in cache. Once you make request again for same URL or image it will directly load image from cache if available.

Also, if you don't want to do any specific operation in block, then simply use **setImageWithURL:placeholderImage**.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I have disabled network, and tried to scroll up and down my tableView. Success block called, and images didn't disappeared.

Comment: It will only remove cache if you delete the application.

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic: That's not true, cache will be cleared if a storage space low issue occurs. OS will clear the cache at that time automatically

Comment: And I can't to release it? For example If I have VC_A and VC_B, in VC_B i have image loading. VC_A > VC_B > VC_A (vc_b is dealloced) All VC_B images still in cache?

Comment: @Arthur, Yes Images will be in cache.